# Hebrew doesn't work in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, hebrew

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.5 with LibreOffice. I was able to write documents in Hebrew without problems and at some point Hebrew stopped working.

I have no idea what caused this problem, but now I can't type Hebrew at all in LibreOffice - cursor doesn't move and characters don't appear. If I open Hebrew document, all Hebrew characters are invisible.
In other applications Hebrew works fine.

My LibreOffice version is 3.5.7.2.
Any ideas?

Comment: Dima, I am not suggesting that you should update to LO 5.0.0.5 available in ppa:libreoffice/ppa, but can you tell us if you don't for any reason at all ? It is just that LO 3.5.x seems very far away by now.

Comment: Could it be that somehow you are missing a font. I doubt that this may be it, but did you check your language support in the LO option settings ?

Comment: I guess you have iBus configured to run with Hebrew and to be able to write from right to left. Did you register any change there ?

Comment: I used Update Manager to keep my system up-to-date and didn't realize that there is new major release of LibreOffice.
I installed latest LO and it solved the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help. I posted the answer in case you want to mark it as such.     Out of curiosity, do you use iBus along with a western script terminal, such as En_US.utf-8 for Hebrew ?

Comment: No, I don't use iBus. I just added Hebrew layout to Keyboard Layouts in Ubuntu settings. That's it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update to LO 5.0.0.5, aka " LO fresh" using the following `ppa:libreoffice/ppa` instead of downloading the deb packages.

The above repo will allow a permanent updating as new versions come out (hence the name "LO fresh"), whereas installing from the .deb files would not, because they are purposefully built on an "older baseline for [maximum compatibility](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/08/install-libreoffice-50-in-ubuntu-or.html)".

In the terminal, do per usual:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:libreoffice/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

Your configuration files should be preserved but you will see that option settings under `Menu | Tools > Options` are expanded.

Enjoy !